# NSDictionary with no data at all

Tags: ios, file, nsdictionary, swift

I am trying to save data into the plist file I created from Xcode.

```
var dict: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: plistPath);

dict = NSMutableDictionary(dict.setValue(speedString, forKey: "Speed"));

if (!dict.writeToFile(plistPath, atomically: true)) {
    NSLog("Failed to save data");
}
```

The dictionary safely wrote to the file.
But the problem is I set a break point after the `if` statement, the debugger showed that the NSDictionary has 0key/value pair, which is weird. In my Xcode, I already added a key/value pair in it.

I added this code to test

```
if (dict.valueForKey("Speed") == nil) {
    NSLog("Key missing");
}
```

The console did print out "Key missing".

Comment: The debugger is broken.

Comment: I added a new code to prove my current problem. And not that the debugger is spoiled

Comment: Because your second line is meaningless. I am surprised that it even compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second line creates a new dictionary. So you are throwing away the dictionary you read in the first line. Thus you are not appending to your dictionary, you are replacing it with a new empty dictionary.

Comment: Also this is Swift. You should be working with Dictionary, not NSMutableDictionary.